# Laravel 8 Does Not Update Information From Database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to update my user information from database. I have this as form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.update' , ['profile' => Auth::user()->id]) }}" class="form">
    <div class="form-group BSinaBold ">
        <input id="location" type="text" class="form-control" name="location" value="{{ Auth::user()->location }}" required autocomplete="location" autofocus>
    </div> 
</form>
```

And at the Controller, I put this in the method `update`:

```
public function update(Request $request, $profile)
    {
        $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
           'location' => 'required'
        ])->validated();

        $user = User::findOrFail($profile);

        $user->update([
            'location' => $validate_data['location']
        ]);

        return back();
    }
```

But now the problem is, it does not update `location`. I mean there is no error appearing and no update at all!

So what's going wrong here, how can I fix this?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys,

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at your User model's fallible fields? You cannot use `update()` will ignore fields not on that list.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Just to mention I think there is a typo in @NMahurin comment, they mean `fillable` and it is a measure against "Mass assignment" https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code provided, you are updating data from $validate_data, update your code to use the request data

```
$user = User::find($profile);

$user->location = request('location');

$user->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead manually creating the validator, you could use the `validate` method provided by the `Illuminate\Http\Request` object:

```
$validated = $request->validate([ 'location' => 'required' ]);
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)

---

Then you can mass update the record (note you doesn't need to retrive the record to update it, just update it):

```
User::where('id', $profile)
      ->update($validated);
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-updates)

---

However, before using the `update` method, you will need to specify either a `fillable` or `guarded` property on your model class.

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        // other fields here...,
        'location',
    ];
}
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)